# Create 10*10 table using javascript and populate cells with colors from black to white

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made 10*10 table using JavaScript. And I want to populate the cells with colors.

In the first cell should be black color and in sequence it should be white color in last cell. How to do that. While clicking on one cell the color of that cell should be filled in one different Box(div). I write some code . It fills the cells with colors but that color not come in sequence.

**Here is code**

```js
function Generate() {
  var row = document.getElementById('txtrow').value;
  var col = document.getElementById('txtcolumn').value;
  var divTable = document.getElementById('divTable');
  var str;
  var i, j;
  str = '<table border="1" width="100%">';
  var clr = 0x000000;
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    str += '<tr>';
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      str += '<td style="background-color:#' + clr + ';" onclick=change("#' + clr + '");>&nbsp;</td>';
      clr = clr + 0x28f5;;
    }
    str += '</tr>';
  }
  str += '</table>';
  divTable.innerHTML = str;
}

function change(v) {
  var div1 = document.getElementById('divText');
  div1.style.backgroundColor = v;
}
```

```html
rows
<input type="text" id="txtrow" value="10" />
<br />
<br />colms
<input type="text" id="txtcolumn" value="10" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="Generate();">
<br />
<div style="width: 500px; height: 300px;" id="divTable"></div>

<div id="divText" style="border: solid 1px #000; width: 300px; height: 200px;">
```

Comment: Can you clarify this: `While clicking on one cell the color of that cell should be filled in one different Box(div)` It's not clear what you want to happen when you click a cell.

Comment: If you want a rainbow or something, you have to realize that representing color in hexadecimal is different than rgb. Hexadecimal colors values are split into three parts, with the first corresponding to the red channel, the second to blue, ect. For example, 100 in hex is 64, so an rgb value of (100,100,100) would be 646464 in hex.

Comment: When the cells will fill with colors.If i click on one of the cell the color of that cell should fill other Div tag which is under of the table. with same color as the color of that cell..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors are made of 3 components, red, green and blue, which take each one byte (two hex digits) in the hex code version.

To have a greyscale gradient from black to white, you need to add the same amount of red, green and blue. Also, you need to provide the color in the right format.

I changed your code to increment just the grey value. The increment is computed based on the number of rows and columns. The (floating point) grey value is converted to an integer, and that is used to created an rgb color.

```js
function Generate() {
     var row = document.getElementById('txtrow').value;
     var col = document.getElementById('txtcolumn').value;
     var divTable = document.getElementById('divTable');
     var str;
     var i, j;
     str = '<table border="1" width="100%">';
     var grey = 0;
     var increment = 255/(row * col);
     var greyInt;
     var color;
     for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
       str += '<tr>';
       for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
         greyInt = Math.floor(grey);
         color = 'rgb(' + greyInt + ',' + greyInt + ',' + greyInt +')';
         str += '<td style="background-color:' + color + ';" onclick=change(' + color + '");>&nbsp;</td>';
         grey += increment;
       }
       str += '</tr>';
     }
     str += '</table>';
     divTable.innerHTML = str;
   }

   function change(v) {
     var div1 = document.getElementById('divText');
     div1.style.backgroundColor = v;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is example hope you need !  ( *I don't sure about color random algoritm.* )

```js
    function Generate()
{
    var row = document.getElementById('txtrow').value;
    var col = document.getElementById('txtcolumn').value;
    var divTable = document.getElementById('divTable');
    var str;
    var i, j;
    str = '<table border="1" width="100%">';

    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        str += '<tr>';
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++){
            str += '<td style="background-color:'+coloralogoritm()+';");>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        str += '</tr>';
    }
    str += '</table>';
    divTable.innerHTML = str;
}
  var r = 0;
  var g = 0;
  var b= 0;

function coloralogoritm(){
            r += parseInt(Math.random() * 10); 
            g += parseInt(Math.random() * 10); 
            b += parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
  return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
rows <input type="text" id="txtrow" value="10"/><br /><br />
colms <input type="text" id="txtcolumn" value="10" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Genrate" onclick="Generate();"><br />
<div style="width: 500px; height: 300px;" id="divTable"></div>

<div id="divText" style="border: solid 1px #000; width: 300px; height: 200px;">
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hope this guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code appears to be that the variable 'clr' is oosing digits. It is treated as a number while calculating the next color.

Basically you are starting with 0x000000 and adding 0x28f5 in the loop.
0x000000 + 0x28f5 = 0x28f5 (which is getting converted to base 10 = 10485 , and this is the value you are supplying for background color assignment ) when using the background color assignment, you want to make use of '6' (six) digits.

you can write a small function to calculate and also pad the final 'clr' which gets assigned as the background color.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hex color codes, you should first convert your number to hex color model string.

Try this :

```js
   function Generate() {
     var row = document.getElementById('txtrow').value;
     var col = document.getElementById('txtcolumn').value;
     var divTable = document.getElementById('divTable');
     //to work with any random col and row, we should compute the diffrence between 2 numbers.
     //this diffrence variable and clc number will keep just one number for green or blue or red
     //then we multiply it to 0x10101 for other colors.
     var diffrence = 0xFF / (row*col - 1);
     var str;
     var i, j;
     str = '<table border="1" width="100%">';
     var clr = 0x000000;
     for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
       str += '<tr>';
       for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
         //Convert number to hex color code(with defined function).
         //we will round the number here to avoid disordering the sequence
         var color = convertNummberToHexaColor(Math.round(clr) * 0x10101);
         str += '<td style="background-color:#' + color + ';" onclick=change("#' + color + '");>&nbsp;</td>';
         //your gap number was not what you want
         clr = clr + diffrence;
       }
       str += '</tr>';
     }
     str += '</table>';
     divTable.innerHTML = str;
   }

   function change(v) {
     var div1 = document.getElementById('divText');
     div1.style.backgroundColor = v;
   }

   //defining a function to convert our number
   function convertNummberToHexaColor(number){
     return ("000000"+number.toString(16)).substr(-6);  
   }
```

```html
rows
<input type="text" id="txtrow" value="10" />
<br />
<br />colms
<input type="text" id="txtcolumn" value="10" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Genrate" onclick="Generate();">
<br />
<div style="width: 500px; height: 300px;" id="divTable"></div>

<div id="divText" style="border: solid 1px #000; width: 300px; height: 200px;">
```